# size views within UIStackView dymicaly

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

I want to have a UIStackView with a horizontal alignment and center distribution that allows for a dynamically changing number of buttons to be added and allows those buttons, that have a constant aspect ratio of 1:1, to change their size so they all fit inside the stack view (or the container).

The button height should always be the height of the container, but if the total width of all the buttons with the spacing in between exceeds the width of the container, then I want the button height to shrink always with respect to the aspect ratio.

I tried setting the top of all the buttons in the stack view to <= to the top of the StackView but that keeps the buttons in the minimum height. 
if I fix the top anchor to be 0 then after a number of buttons the aspect ration constraint gets ignored and the buttons deform.

if you require any more information, please do ask.

Thanks.

**Edit**. 
Ex. If I have UIStackView of 1024 width and 200 height with a spacing of 10, and I want to fit 4 buttons, then I have 10+200+10+200+10+200+10+200+10 = 850 which is less than 1024 so the buttons all fit with maximum height being the height of the container. 
but If I add another button I will have 
10+200+10+200+10+200+10+200+10+200+10 = 1060 which is larger than 1024. My buttons then seem to ignore the aspect ratio and deform, where I only want them to have height == width instead of width == height.

**Edit 2**
[image: 4 buttons 1024 x 200]

[image: 6 buttons 1024 x 200]

Comment: Do you mean horizontal axis? Can you provide a picture of what you want. It's very hard to understand a written description of a visual design. Much easier to see a picture showing what you want.

Comment: @Fogmeister updated. I want to keep the spacing and the aspect ratio. 
Please also have in mind that I need this to respect size classes so it works for iphone and ipad as well.

Comment: OK, so it should grow from the centre? If there's only one button that should be right in the centre? OK, that bits easy. What do you want to happen when there are too many? In your example you show them being clipped into rectangular shapes. What do you want to happen instead?